# Смена типа ввода поля, в зависимости от избранного раньше, yii2

Tags: php, javascript, yii2

Здравствуйте, мне нужно сделать смену второго параметра в зависимости от первого. 
Есть 5 типов ввода - text, image, textarea, ckeditor, checkbox

И в зависимости от выбранного типа ввода, выводить нужное поле - текстовое,поле загрузки и т.д.

```
<?= $list =  $form->field($model, 'type')->dropDownList([
                    'input' => 'Input',
                    'image' => 'Image',
                    'textarea' => 'TextArea',
                    'fck' => 'FCK Editor',
                    'checkbox' => 'CheckBox',
                ],
                    ['id' => 'js-type']);
                ?>
```

Выбор нужного параметра type

Скрипт, для show, hide

```
<?php
                //script JS
                $script = <<< JS
   $('#js-type').on('change', function() {
  var selection = $(this).val();

  $('div#values > div').hide();
  $("#"+selection).show(); 
});
JS;
                $this->registerJs($script, View::POS_END);
                ?>
```

И сами поля

```
<div id="values">
                    <div id="input" style="display:none;">
                        <?= $form->field($model, 'value')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]); ?>
                    </div>
                    <div id="image" style="display:none;">
                        <?= $form->field($model, 'value')->fileInput(); ?>
                    </div>
                    <div id="textarea" style="display:none;">
                        <?= $form->field($model, 'value')->textarea(['rows' => '6', 'maxlength' => true]) ?>
                    </div>
                    <div id="fck" style="display:none;">
                        <?= $form->field($model, 'value')->widget(CKEditor::className(), [
                            'options' => ['rows' => 3],
                            'preset' => 'full'
                        ]) ?>
                    </div>
                    <div id="checkbox" style="display:none;">
                        <?= $form->field($model, 'value')->checkbox() ; ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Не отправляет данные, т.е. если я выберу тип input - текстовое поле, заполняю данными. Но при отправке ошибка - Необходимо заполнить «Значение». Видимо из-за того, что есть еще поля

```
$form->field($model, 'value'),
```

потому, что если оставить только 1 поле, все работет. 
Как можно выйти из ситуации, потому как таким способом не выйдет ?
Как менять только лишь значения после
 **$form->field($model, 'value')** на ->*textInput*, ->*textarea* и т.д ?

Answer (score 1):

Не вникал в суть, и возможно лучше пойти другим путем, но если сама суть вопроса - "как вызвать метод из строки", то примерно так:

```
$methods = [
    0 => 'input',
    1 => 'image',
    2 => 'textarea',
    3 => 'fck',
    4 => 'checkbox'
];
$type_id = 0;

$form->{$methods[$type_id]}($model, 'value');
```